# Is there any way in Clickhouse to skip certain data for the main table but leave it for the materialized view?

Tags: clickhouse

Tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE main;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW main_minute
AS SELECT
...
FROM main;
```

Use case:
I want all the data to be inserted into the `main_minute`, however I would like to skip some entries (let's say, by some field) within `main` table.

At the moment the only idea I have is to make `main` table as `Null Engine` - `main_null`. Add additional view `main_filter` that will filter entries by the field and set `TO` field to the `main` table. So filtered entries will end up within the `main` table. Like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE main_null ENGINE NULL;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW main_filter
TO main
AS SELECT
...
FROM main_null;

CREATE TABLE main;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW main_minute
AS SELECT
...
FROM main_null;
```

Is there any other way to achieve that?

Comment: MV & Null Engine is the only way

Comment: yep, I think you're on the right way,

Comment: but I didn't understand which table you would like to use for the insert?

it's a main_null?

Comment: @Slach yes. it is main_null